# how to integrate the nested array response from the api into nested recyclerview in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nestedrecyclerview

I'm trying to integrate the nested array response from the api into nested recyclerview in android
I integrate the response but i couldn't get values from the response.`  private void loadJson() {
//creating a string request to send request to the url
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, myUrl,
new Response.Listener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The response is" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Response is" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //getting the whole json object from the response
                        JSONObject emp=(new JSONObject(response)).getJSONObject("getquestions");
                        String empname=emp.getString("name");
                        int empid=emp.getInt("id");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the question name is"+empname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the question id is"+empid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                      /*  JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String title = movieObject.getString("q_name");
                        Log.e("question","-->"+title);*/

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

`

Comment: Hi, please post some code which shows your specific problem and what you have already tried.

Comment: Is there proper response in Logs? Please share the response too and try formatting on JsonFormatter online.

Comment: For nested recycler view create another adapter and call it in onBindViewholder() for each time